# How to display text of reference

Tags: hyperref, links

If I put

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

% ... %
\begin{align}
  Label \label{lab:one}
\end{align}
Reference: \ref{lab:one}
```

I get a hyperlink to my label (puts "Reference: 1" with a clickable 1). Instead, I occasionally want to put the label unclickable (hence a non-clickable 1 in this case), but still use hyperref for other parts. Never figured out how to do that.

Comment: Use `\ref*{lab:one}` instead..., see ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-190005 of `hyperref` manual

Comment: I suspected it woould be easy as that. Thanks!